# Accessing buttons added from inner.html on page_load from page_load

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm trying to create an html table with information from my user info table in my database. I've successfully managed to display the information but I'm not managing to add a delete button next to each user (a row in the table).

Basically I've retreived my whole user info table from the sql database, then I looped through it and added rows and cells inside an already created div (It only has the opening  tag because I added a first row for the heading)

I assigned each dynamicly create button an ID according to its username and tried to loop through and check if any of the buttons are pressed to remove but Its not triggering.

I'm a beginner and pretty stumped on the right way to do this, I'd be super grateful for any help.

the html:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Admin.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
    <link href="css/admin.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">

    <header class="grid_9">פאנל מנהל</header>

    <div class="grid_9 block_head"> טבלת משתמשים </div>
    <div class="block grid_9" id="user_block" runat="server">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>שם משתמש</td>
                <td>סיסמא</td>
                <td>אימייל</td>
                <td>הרשאות</td>
                <td>מחיקה</td>
            </tr>


    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

The c#

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if(Session["Admin"] == null || Session["Admin"].Equals(0))
        {
            Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('אין לך את ההרשאות המתאימות לצפות בדף זה');window.location.href = 'Default.aspx';</script>");
        }
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM [userinfo]";
        DataSet data = Database.GetDataOffline(sql);



            foreach (DataRow row in data.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                user_block.InnerHtml += "<tr><td>" + row[1] + "</td><td>" + row[2] + "</td><td>" + row[3] + "</td>";
                if (row[4].ToString().Equals("1")) { user_block.InnerHtml += "<td>" + "מנהל" + "</td><td><input type='button' value='מחק' id=" + row[1] + " runat='server'></td></tr>"; }
                else { user_block.InnerHtml += "<td>" + "משתמש" + "</td><td><input type='button' value='מחק' id=" + row[1] + " runat='server'></td></tr>"; }
            }
            user_block.InnerHtml += "</table>";



            foreach (DataRow row in data.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                string user = row[1].ToString();
                if (Request.Form["" + user] != null)
                {
                    Response.Write("Removing");
                    string userSql = "DELETE * FROM [userinfo] WHERE [username] ='" + user + "'";
                    Database.UpdateData(userSql);
                    Response.Redirect("admin.aspx");
                }
            }




    }
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you aren't using something like a GridView or at least a Repeater control?

Comment: I'm honestly a total beginner and I don't know what those things are!

Comment: They make what your trying to do a lot easier. are you using the Visual Studio development environment?

Comment: yes I am, I read up on them but up until now i've only been using html elements and I'm not sure how to do this with asp elements

Comment: Best bet is to learn the Gridview control and an appropriate datasource control. My suggestion...find a good tutorial on youtube or the MSDN website and go from there. There is far to much to explain.

Comment: Will I still have the same css flexibility when using these controls?

Comment: Yes, all asp controls render to standard html. They just give you greater ability to manipulate and display data programmatically. All displayable asp.net web controls give you the ability to apply css styling via CssClass property. Further, you can apply row level styling via GridView.RowDataBound event. Also, look into Themes which allows you to apply the same styling across all controls at the Project level for look and feel consistency.  there are many many ways to style elements and data, far more than I can go into here